# The instance member '_localNotifications' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

I followed a YouTube video to add push notifications to my flutter app. The video is only 5 months old but is already outdated on some methods.

Here is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0zGEbiDJcQ

One thing I am having trouble with is with this code:

```
final _androidChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high importance channel',
    'High importance notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications',
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
  );

  final _localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;
  }

  Future initPushNotifications() async {
    // This line is for iOS
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
            alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      final notification = message.notification;
      if (notification == null) return;

      _localNotifications.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _androidChannel.id,
            _androidChannel.name,
            channelDescription: _androidChannel.description,
            icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
      );
    });
  }

  Future initLocalNotifications() async {
    //const iOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android);

    await _localNotifications.initialize(settings,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:  (payload) {
      final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload as String));
      handleMessage(message);
    });
  }

  final platform = _localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
  await platform?.createNotificationChannel(_androidChannel);

  Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('Title: ${message.notification?.title}');
    print('Body: ${message.notification?.body}');
    print('Payload: ${message.data}');
  }

  void initNotifications() async {
    final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    final deviceToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();

    ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).updateDeviceToken(deviceToken!);
    initPushNotifications();
    initLocalNotifications();
  }
```

I am getting an error where I am trying to assign the variable "platform" from the _localNotifications.

Here is the error message:

```
The instance member '_localNotifications' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _localNotifications

Type: FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
```

I'm too new to Flutter to know what is wrong here.
How do I fix this?
Thanks